# Print some HEX colors to view them

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following colors:

```
c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc", "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c")
```

I would like to make simple plot so I can see the colors, either with `ggplot2` or base R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `colorspace` for sample plot

```
library(colorspace)
demoplot(c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc", "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c"), type = "bar")
```

Comment: This requires `colorspace` version >= `v1.4-0` released Jan 2019. It was not in earlier versions of the package.

Comment: Right, I use package ‘colorspace’ version 1.4-1. Thank you MrFlick

Answer (score 5):

With `ggplot2` you can do

```
library(ggplot2)
show_colors <- function(colors) { 
  ggplot(data.frame(id=seq_along(colors), color=colors)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(id, 1, fill=color)) + 
    scale_fill_identity()
}

colors <- c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc", "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c")
show_colors(colors)
```

which returns

[image]

Or you could turn it sideways and print the color names

```
show_colors2 <- function(colors) { 
  ggplot(data.frame(id=seq_along(colors), color=colors)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(1, id, fill=color)) + 
    geom_text(aes(1, id, label=color)) + 
    scale_fill_identity()
}
show_colors2(colors)
```

[image]

This base graphics you could do

```
show_colors <- function(colors) {
  ncol <- length(colors)
  plot(0,0, ylim=c(0, 1), xlim=c(0, ncol), type="n")
  rect(0:(ncol-1), 0, 1:ncol, 1, col = colors)
}
show_colors(colors)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe a more elegant way, but this shows what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
    x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
    y = rep(1,6),
    c = c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc", "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c")
 )
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, col=c))+geom_point(size=8)
```

---

**This was wrong and I know the answers from above are the better ones**
But I wanted to make the improvements needed to offer at least a correct answer - at least what the choice of colors is concerned:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  y = rep(1,6),
  c = c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc",
        "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c")
 )

farbe <- c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc",
          "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c")

ggplot(df, aes(x,y, col=c))+geom_point(size=8)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_manual(
    name="Colors",
    values = farbe,
    breaks = c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc",
               "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c"))
```

[image]

Comment: Those actually aren't the right colors. Those are the default ggplot color pallete colors.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Flick. I did not recognize this.

Answer (score 0):

A light-weight option that requires only `grid`,

```
grid::grid.raster(t(c("#bbb487", "#066e9f", "#e2dfcc", "#4e766d", "#dd8047", "#d8b25c")), interp=FALSE)
```